# Emacs find-other-file issue

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to use ff-find-other-file by modifying the cc-other-file-alist like this

```
(setq cc-other-file-alist
'(
("\\.cxx$" my-other-file-fun)
("\\.hxx$" my-other-file-fun)
))
```

and `my-other-file-fun`is returning a list of matches. The problem is when I open a cxx file and call `ff-find-other-file`, the function `my-other-file-fun` is not getting called. But If I open a hxx file and call `ff-find-other-file` my custom function is getting invoked and I'm seeing the correct result. What could have gone wrong ? I'm using emacs-24.1 on linux

Thanks,

Surya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to call the function, using backquote then:

```
(setq cc-other-file-alist
  `(
    ("\\.cxx$" ,(my-other-file-fun))
    ("\\.hxx$" ,(my-other-file-fun))))
```

if `my-other-file-fun` returns a list of matching extensions, or even cache the result on a variable using `let`.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm getting an error saying invalid symbol. But one observation is that, I'm not getting the error when I call `ff-find-other-file` for a .hxx file, but error for .cxx file. That means, ff-find-other-file is not looking at cc-other-file-alist when called for a .cxx file. That is strange. I'm planning to debug ff-find-other-file

Comment: What symbol is invalid exacly?

Comment: Nevermind, I found out the problem. When in CXX file, I was calling ff-find-other-file when the cursor is on #include line and hence it was trying to open the include header instead of corresponding header. I'll accept this answer anyway.